# CardView vs LinearLayout - images scalling issue

Tags: android, imageview, autoscaling

Please look at following 2 layouts.

First, `cardview`:
http://pastebin.com/iYzUiDQ7

Second, `LinearLayout` only (layout is actually the same as the one inside my CardView):
http://pastebin.com/xijHZCPw

So, second layout contains `WebView` component + single `LinearLayout` under it that should represent the same layout as single `CardView` item.

It works, however... I'm having problems with scaling images. If I  set very large image as image for my `ImageView` placed on `CardView`, it will be scaled nicely to fit on my `CardView`. `CardView's` height won't be changed, instead, image will be scaled proportionally to fit.

But when I'm trying to do the same with second layout I linked, my `LinearLayout` changes its height if I set large image. How should I change my second layout to get the same effect for my `LinearLayout`, placed at bottom of my screen?

Comment: I get the difference

Comment: so basically you want is linearlayout below webview. and linear layout should wrap it size for large image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the difference between the two layout.

you had set the layout_height with 100dp in CardView. so the height of LinearLayout in CardView will does not beyond that. But you set the layout_height with wrap_content in you second LinearLayout.

Try to set maxHeight or layout_height with digit to deal with you problem.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I set both height and layout_height to 100dp and it seems it resolved my problem.